# SELECT COLUMN, OTHERCOLUMNS FROM TABLE

Tags: mysql

I Have A Several Tables That Have A UUID As The Primary Key.

I'm Using Binary(16) As The Column Data Type And I'm Populating The Column With `UUID_TO_BIN()` Function.

I Want To Select All The Columns From A Particular Table And While I Know I Can Specify All The Column Name i.e `SELECT BIN_TO_UUID(id) AS ID, COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3 FROM Table;`

I Want To Ask If There's A Way To Do The Select Like:
`SELECT BIN_TO_UUID(id) AS ID, REST_OF_COLUMNS FROM TABLE;` Because This Particular Table Has A Lot Of Columns.

Thanks..

Database Type: MySQL
Engine: InnoDB

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can do `SELECT BIN_TO_UUID(id) AS ID, * FROM ...`, but the binary `id` column will be there.

Use [invisible columns](https://lefred.be/content/mysql-invisible-column-part-iii/). Make the `bin_to_uuid(id)` a generated function. Then you can just use `*`.

Note: MariaDB has a [uuid data type](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/uuid-data-type/) to make this sort of thing easier. - [user158002](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/158002/danblack)